# C++ overload resolution always resort to alias arg. over others as the arg. valid to all

Tags: c++, function, overloading

How do we make (sure) C++ overload resolution will always resort to alias arg. than normal arg., so e.g. must pick

```
int func(string& s) {
// ...
}
```

over

```
int func(string s) { //...
}
```

when the argument valid to both?
thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the second function is supposed be named `func` too (instead of `over func()` which is no valid function name), then it can be an ambigious overload, depending on how you call it.

Answer (score 1):

If the argument is valid to both (eg `std::string`), then the code will not compile (GCC9.2) because of the ambiguity

> error: call of overloaded 'func(std::string&)' is ambiguous

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qbvrAR

If you pass `const char*` or something else, which is default constructible to `std::string`, then the function, which takes copy of a string, will be called. 
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/DGSuEz

There is (not known to me) no way how to tell the compiler that he should prefer reference function over copy. You can check this snippet where I'm trying to explicitly call the reference, but compilation fails again due tu ambiguity:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/gZSdyj